# Need Website rating apis for iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-api, rating, google-api-client

I want website rating api that gives me the status of website in different search engines. i want to send Keyword, Website and Search engine in api and they should return me the ranking of the website. so please can you suggest me that type of apis.

If api returns me data in xml format that very good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at http://www.alexa.com/

The developer tools are located here: http://www.alexa.com/siteowners/data